# Writing and reading shared memory for getting square of a number by client server method

Tags: c, shared-memory

this is the program for server in shared memory which will calculate the square of a number and then the client will be able to access it 
SERVER::

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


#define SHMSZ     27

int main()
{
    char c;
    int shmid;
    key_t key;
    char *shm, *s;
    int i,n;
    key = 5678;
    if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHMSZ, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0) {
        perror("shmget");
        return 1;
    }
    if ((shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == NULL) {
        perror("shmat");
        return 1;
    }


     while (*shm != '*')
        sleep(1);
    s = shm;

   s++;
   char m=*s;

   n=(int)m;

    int r=square(n);// called function square function 
    s=shm;
    s++;

    int a=1000;
    for (i=0;i<4;i++){
        *s = (char)(r/a+48);
        r=r%a;
        a=a/10;
        s++;
        }
    s = NULL;
    *shm='%';

    while (*shm != '$')
        sleep(1);

    return 0;
}
int square(int n){
    int a,b;
    a=n/10;
    b=n%10;
    int res=a*a*100+a*b*2*10+b*b;
    return res;
}
```

CLIENT::

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


#define SHMSZ     27

int main()
{
    int shmid;
    key_t key;
    char *shm, *s;

    /*
     * We need to get the segment named
     * "5678", created by the server.
     */
    key = 5678;

    /*
     * Locate the segment.
     */
    if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHMSZ, 0666)) < 0) {
        perror("shmget");
        return 1;
    }

    /*
     * Now we attach the segment to our data space.
     */
    if ((shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (char *) -1) {
        perror("shmat");
        return 1;
    }

     int i,n1;
     char n;
    s=shm;
     printf("Enter a 2 digit number : ");

     scanf("%2d",&n1);

     n=(char)n1;



     s++;
     *s=n;
     *shm='*';

     while (*shm != '%')
        sleep(1);
     s=shm;
     s++;
    for (i=0; *s != NULL && i<4;i++){
        printf("%c",*s);
        s++;
        }
    putchar('\n');

    /*
     * Finally, change the first character of the 
     * segment to '*', indicating we have read 
     * the segment.
     */
    *shm = '$';

    return 0;
}
```

In the server program ,from int a=1000 what is the purpose of using for loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the following code is basically used for converting the  calculated integer number to a character string.

```
for (i=0;i<4;i++){
        *s = (char)(r/a+48);
        r=r%a;
        a=a/10;
        s++;
        }
```

it is basically required so that it will be posted as a string in shared memeory.

Answer (score 1):

That's basically a simple `itoa()` that converts the calculated number into a string (note that the ascii code of '0' is 48, does that ring a bell?).

Comment: Ok... I was thinking at a completely different scenario , so was'nt able to get at this solution .